# How to find the PDF of one random variable when the PDF of another random variable and the relationship between the two random variables are known?

Tags: random-variables

The probability density function of random variable X is given as  $ f_x(x) = \lambda e^ {-\lambda x} , x \ge 0. $ A new random variable $ Y = e^ {-\lambda X}$ is formed. Find the PDF of Y.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are shortcuts, but we will use a basic method. The idea is to find the *cumulative distribution* function of $Y$, and then *differentiate* to find the density function. We have
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(e^{-\lambda X}\le y)=\Pr(-\lambda X \le \log y).$$
(We took the logarithm: this preserves inequalities.) Thus 
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr\left(X\ge -\frac{\log y}{\lambda}\right).$$
We know that $\Pr(X\ge t)=e^{-\lambda t}$, if $t$ is positive.  If $t$ is negative, the probability is $1$.

Substitute for $t$. There is dramatic simplification. The $\lambda$'s cancel, and we get $e^{\log y}$, that is $y$. But note this is correct only when $-\log y$ is $\ge 0$, that is, when $y\le 1$. If $y\gt 1$, $F_Y(y)=1$.

Finally, differentiate. The density function is $1$ on the interval $(0,1)$, and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice "change of variables" formula for doing this.  If $g$ is a monotonic function, then

$$
f_Y(y)=\left\vert\frac{d}{dy}(g^{-1}(y))\right\vert f_X(g^{-1}(y))
$$

So, let $g(x)=e^{-\lambda x}$; this is a monotonic function, so the formula applies.  $g^{-1}(y)=-\ln(y)/\lambda$, and so

$$
\left\vert\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right\vert=\frac{1}{\lambda y}
$$

putting the pieces together, we get:

$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\lambda y}\lambda \exp[-\lambda g^{-1}(y)]=\frac{1}{y}\exp[\ln(y)]=1
$$

Notice that since $x\geq 0$, $0<y\leq 1$ (assuming $\lambda>0$) so this distribution makes sense.

Comment: I know this is a decade old, but this is such an interesting transformation! Can you please supply a proof of this?(preferably one that does not go back to CDFs)