# spherically normal-distributed random variable as composite random variable of direction and length

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, spherical-coordinates

I want to find the PDF $f_\boldsymbol{X}(\vec{x})$ of a random variable $\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with positivly normally distributed length $|\boldsymbol{X}|=|x|$ where $x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and a unit direction (in the unit sphere $S^3$), i.e. $\hat{\boldsymbol{X}} = \boldsymbol{X}|\boldsymbol{X}|^{-1}\sim\mathcal{U}(S^3)$.

Since $\boldsymbol{X}$ results from the trivial composition $\boldsymbol{X}=|\boldsymbol{X}|\hat{\boldsymbol{X}}$, it should be possible to construct $f_\boldsymbol{X}$ from the normal and uniform distribution. A similar approach is used for for different compositions and PDFs, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256044/how-to-find-the-pdf-of-one-random-variable-when-the-pdf-of-another-random-variab) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256044/how-to-find-the-pdf-of-one-random-variable-when-the-pdf-of-another-random-variab).

My attempt was the following:
Let $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^3$. We know that
$$
Pr(\hat{\boldsymbol{X}}\in\omega) = \frac{|\omega ~\cap~S^3|}{|S^3|}
$$
and thus
$$
Pr(\boldsymbol{X}\in\omega) = Pr(\hat{\boldsymbol{X}} \in \omega|\boldsymbol{X}|^{-1}).
$$
Now my most intuitive next step is
$$
Pr(\hat{\boldsymbol{X}} \in \omega|\boldsymbol{X}|^{-1}) =\frac{|\omega |\boldsymbol{X}|^{-1}~\cap~S^3|}{|S^3|} 
$$
which clearly is non-sense, since the random variable $|\boldsymbol{X}|^{-1}$ apprears in the CDF.

How do I go on from here? I would very much like to solve this using first principles and bare probabilities.

Comment: Did you mean for the length of $X$ to be normal with zero mean? I believe it should be strictly positive.
$$$$
For the uniform direction part, check out https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Comment: @GáborPálovics: Your right. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$X = R \begin{bmatrix} \sin\theta \cos\phi \\ \sin\theta \sin\phi \\ \cos \phi \end{bmatrix}$$
Then if you choose $U, V \sim Uni(0, 1)$ i.i.d, you can get a uniform distribuiton on the sphere R, by using:
$$\theta = 2 \pi u$$
$$\phi = \arccos (2v - 1)$$

So what you want is
$$U, V \sim Uni(0, 1)$$
$$R \sim |N(0, \sigma^2)|$$
$$\theta = 2 \pi u$$
$$\phi = \arccos (2v - 1)$$

For more informationon this, see: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Comment: As I pointed out in my question, I would like to understand how to get the PDF from the composite PDFs of lengths and direction, in the way the provided likes do.

Comment: Your example is different from what you referenced. In the referenced examples, we know the exact relationship between $X$ and $Y$. Here this relationship is not so trivial. You can arrive to a setting with well-defined relationship by using the equations above. Then you can calculte the joint and marginal pdfs with the same methodology.

Comment: You're right! The composition into length and direction leads to a dead end, I guess. Thank you!